# Exchange 2010 Export of PST with Date Range

Tags: exchange-2010, powershell

I'm trying to Export one of our Mailboxes into a .PST file and having problems finding the right cmdlets. We are trying to export the past 30 days of a users mailbox, both Received and Sent into one .PST File

This is what I've tried so far, but without any luck.

```
New-MailboxExportRequest -ContentFilter {(Received -lt ’04/01/2010′) -and (Received -ge ’03/01/2010′) -or (Sent -lt ’04/01/2010′) -and (Sent -ge ’03/01/2010′)} -Mailbox “Pelton” -Name DPeltonExp -FilePath \\ExServer1\Imports\DPelton.pst
```

Please advised as what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You need a few parentheses to make the ContentFilter logic stick. Try this:

```
{((Received -lt ’04/01/2010′) -and (Received -ge ’03/01/2010′)) -or ((Sent -lt ’04/01/2010′) -and (Sent -ge ’03/01/2010′))}
```

**Edit**: I think actually you should use double quotes for the dates in stead of single quotes. It might not matter, but if the above doesn't work, try substituting the single quotes with doubles

Answer (score 0):

While Exporting Data (Send and Receive ) Folder into PST Format. All the data stored in Single File format (PST) and When you try to open the PST File via importing option of Outlook then it will maintain a folder hierarchy and to move data into pst format first you need to create and share folder, to save the desired data into it.

To know, how to create the shared folder, visit [here](https://exchange-server-guide.blogspot.in/2015/11/export-edb-mailbox-to-pst-using-powershell.html), then you need to run Powershell query:

New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox  -ContentFilter {(Received -lt '01/01/2015') -and (Subject -like 'fwd*')} -FilePath \\\.pst

Answer (score 0):

You can run Get-MailboxExportRequest command to get the exports status:

Get-MailboxExportRequest | Get-MailboxExportRequestStatistics

Comment: welcome to the site